# Truncating Log File using C# via Forms

Tags: c#, file, logging, truncate

My forms shows the value of data and log file via this script

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source='"+ ip.Text+"';Initial Catalog='"+ database.Text +"';User ID=1;Password=1");
            // DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            //dt = DateTime.Now;
            SqlDataAdapter sda5 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name, type_desc, size FROM sys.database_files", con);
            DataTable dt5 = new DataTable();
            sda5.Fill(dt5);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt5;
            dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n2";
            con.Close();
```

and after showing data on my forms I have a button below that will truncate this log file.

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source='"+ ip.Text+"';Initial Catalog='"+ database.Text +"';User ID=1;Password=1");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE '" + database.Text + "'" +
            "SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;" +
            "DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 1);"+
            "GO ALTER DATABASE '" + database.Text + "'" + 
            "SET RECOVERY FULL;",con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Truncated"); 
            }
            catch
            {
             MessageBox.Show("Error");
                throw;
            }
            con.Close();
```

but after clicking the truncate button I have this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'db'.
>
> 'RECOVERY' is not a recognized SET option.
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'db'.

Is there  any other way that I can truncate this log file without going through SQL Server Management Studio. And I can truncate it via my forms?

Comment: What is the final text of cmd?

Comment: Hi! Thanks Sir Robert, btw what do you mean cmd? Am I right im going to truncate the log file?

Comment: Or is it much better if I will run a Sqlcommand 4 times on this so it will be receovery, shrinkfile,alter, and recovery?

Comment: I mean what is the command text that is being submitted to SQL Server?  You build the command with this expression: "ALTER DATABASE '" + database.Text + "'" +
            "SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;" +
            "DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 1);"+
            "GO ALTER DATABASE '" + database.Text + "'" + 
            "SET RECOVERY FULL;",con  . Store that value in a string and tell us what it is. It is probable that you will see a syntax error in it.

Comment: Mabuhay! Sir Robert, on our usual script we run on studio was
`code`
USE dbname;
GO
-- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.
ALTER DATABASE dbname
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.
DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 1);  -- here 2 is the file ID for trasaction log file,you can also mention the log file name (dbname_log)
GO
-- Reset the database recovery model.
ALTER DATABASE dbname
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
`code`
Then I convert it to c# with 1 cmd do I need to seperately run this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command script contains a syntax error. If you inspect the [`cmd.CommandText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll find that the command looks like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE 'db'SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 1);GO ALTER DATABASE 'db'SET RECOVERY FULL;
```

When I run that line on a SqlServer 2016 database, [the result is](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/501234)

> Incorrect syntax near 'db'.
> 'RECOVERY' is not a recognized SET option.
> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

This means the command is not correct according to the syntax rules of the [Alter Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) statement and other rules.

At minimum your statement should look like this, where it is important that `GO` is on a line all by itself and the databasename isn't surrounded by single quotes.

```
ALTER DATABASE db SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 1);
GO 
ALTER DATABASE db SET RECOVERY FULL;
```

C# offers [verbatim strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx#Anchor_3) and those come handy here:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format(
@"ALTER DATABASE [{0}] 
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 1);
GO 
ALTER DATABASE [{0}] 
SET RECOVERY FULL;" , 
database.Text),con);
```

You can't use parameters here so you're forced to use string formatting to bring the parameter in your sql statement. Make sure `database.Text` is something you control and cannot be entered by users of your applications, to prevent [SQL injection attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/) from happening.

Comment: Mabuhay! Sir @rene Hi! is {0} means that is it my database? 

after running 
`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`

here is my error 
**Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.**

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sir @rene it works when i deleted the code 
`GO`

Is there any problem which will I encounter if I will omit this one?

Comment: Mabuhay! Sir @rene i forgot everytime we truncated a log file we add [ ] on database like [databasename] because the first character of that database is number. How can i add [] on `database.Text`

Comment: Thanks i edit the SqlConnection

`Initial Catalog='["+ database.Text +"]'`

Comment: Once I run the select query rows and log file iwll show but when I decided to truncate and click the Trancate Button heres what i got.

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot open database "[079PDB]" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'sa'.`

Or it does have error on script because it was declared as string?

Comment: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format(
@"ALTER DATABASE {0} 
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 1);
GO 
ALTER DATABASE {0} 
SET RECOVERY FULL;" , 
database.Text),con);`

Thanks again.

Comment: Solved

`'[' + database.Text  +']'), con);`

Thanks

Comment: You better add those `[` and `]` to the sql statement like I have done in the edited answer